# View Controller From Segue Producing Different Results

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am developing an application that starts at a "Main" View Controller and presents a "Details" View Controller based on the data that is passed from the Main. The problem that I am experiencing is that the details View Controller is displaying inconsistent results (see pictures). I have constraints on the Details View Controller in the storyboard but nothing explicitly in the code. Has any one seen this before? Could it just be a problem with the image?[image]

Comment: Make sure that the UIImageView has `clipsToBounds` set to true

Comment: That was it! Thanks!